# How to use the guard without losing my login information? (Angular 10)

Tags: angular

I implemented 2 guards, one for normal user and one for admin. Whenever I login, I store all the data of the user in a service. However, when I am for example logged in as a user and I try to access a page for admins only, my guard does it's job BUT it also "erases" all the login information stored in my service. So then I have to login all over again. How do I prevent that?

Here is my normaluser guard:

```
 canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if(this.loginAuthenthicationService.isAuthenticated){
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['']);
    return false;
  }
```

Here is my admin guard:

```
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      if(this.loginAuthenthicationService.isAuthenticated && this.loggedUserService.loginCredentials.admin){
        return true;
      }
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      return false;
  }
```

These are my routes & how I use the guards:

```
    {

            path: 'profile',
            loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule),
            data: { preload: false, privilege: 'dashboard' },
            canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]

    },
    {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule),
        data: { preload: false, privilege: 'dashboard' },
        canActivate: [AdminAuthenticationGuard]
    },
```

And here is my service, where I store temporarily userdata:

```
export class LoggedUserService {

  constructor() { }

  loginCredentials = {
    voornaam: "",
    achternaam: "",
    email: "",
    admin: false
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have any login data, you will have to create a service that stores and retrieve them from local storage, and just in the a service. That way even if you get redirected or reload the page you are still logged in.
I don't think you can proceed otherwise.

Comment: Or you can have a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of `this.router.navigate(['']);` line, remove this and it'll be fine

Also, you could redirect users to some 'Access Denied' page

Comment: Try to save your login result using `local Storage` and read from it